# cin doesn't take input as ENTER

Tags: c++, cin

```
char ch[4];  
char* ptr;  
ptr = ch;  
while(1)  
{  
  cin >> *ptr;  
if(*ptr == '\n')  
break;  
ptr++;  
}
```

Here I just wrote a bit of sample code where I am trying to get out of a while loop when user writes ENTER but it's not working. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Reading input into a simple character array is generally a bad idea, since the buffer could overrun and your program could crash or malicious code could execute. Better to use a std::string.

Answer (score 6):

To get a single character, use [`std::istream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get). This should work for getting newlines as well.

But instead of getting characters in a loop until you get a newline, why not just use something like [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
std::string str;
std::getline(cin, str);
```

Or if you only want to get max three characters you can use [`std::istream::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline):

```
char ch[4];
cin.getline(ch, 4, '\n');
```

Comment: Why would one choose `istream::getline()` or `istream::get()` versus using the << operator on `cin`?

Comment: @RandallCook The `>>` operator skips whitespace, which includes newline.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading input into the value of a character. That's what `*ptr` means. I think you want just plain ptr, which is a pointer to an array of characters, which is something that is meant to receive data. What you wrote is basically this:

```
char c;
cin >> c;
```

I don't think that's what you meant, nor would it work even if it were, since as Joachim Pileborg points out above, the `>>` operator skips whitespace like newlines. In general, it is always best to be very robust when it comes to reading input. Provide adequate space, and either use a variable that can grow automatically (like `std::string`) or tell the system how much space you have (like `fgets()`).

Answer (score 1):

The following will read a line:

```
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n );
```

Answer (score 1):

The extraction operator would skip leading white-spaces and stop execution on encountering any subsequent white-space. So, when you want to do something like this, use std::istream::get() or std::istream::getline().